# Socket.io broadcasts everything to everybody in node/express app

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I wondered if someone could help figure out what I am doing wrong:

My client web page initiates a connection with my server, and listens to a long running process whose state is getting updated in the db by a worker process on another thread, emitting updates back to the browser. I define a socket.io connection in the app.post() method. This is handled by the poll() function below (scroll down a bit past the invite checking code)

However, when a new web client connects, it's messages get added to the previous client's as if there were just one channel. Why isn't there a separate unique channel for each browser?

```
//Create server
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    http = require('http'),
    server = http.createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.set('log level', 1); // reduce logging
io.configure(function () {
    io.set("transports", ["xhr-polling"]);
    io.set("polling duration", 10);
});

app.post('/api/users', function (req, res) {
    if (!req.body.auth.accessToken) {
        req.body.auth.accessToken = req.body.auth.authResponse.accessToken;
    } //fb return object is different depending on whether it is a first login or subsequent
    logger.log('debug', '/api/users:POST', req.body);
    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
        socket = socket;
        socket.emit('update', {
            status: 200 //send initialization ping
        });


        //check if user has valid invite, if not try to invite
        db.getTotalUserInvites(function (err_inv, res_total) {

            db.getUserInvite(req.body.fid, function (err_check, res_check) {
                logger.log('debug', 'Total invites issued=' + res_total);

                    //process report - all we need is accesToken, processReport will do the rest
                    mine_fb.processUser(req.body.auth.accessToken, socket, function (User,socket) { //pass channel properly
                        db.getReportStatus(User.fid,socket, function (result,socket) {
                            logger.log('debug', 'report status', result);
                            if (result) {
                                if (socket && (result.report_status == -1)) {
                                    logger.log('debug', 'report already processed. retrieving uniq_id ' + result.uniq_id);
                                    socket.emit('update', {
                                        status: -1,
                                        uniq_id: result.uniq_id
                                    });
                                    return true;
                                } else {
                                    if (socket && (result.report_status >= 0)) {
                                        logger.log('debug', 'we are in the middle of processing report ' + result.uniq_id);
                                        //in this case we become a listener and not a speaker

                                        function poll(socket) {
                                            db.getReportStatus(User.fid, socket,function (r,socket) {
                                                socket.emit('update', { //!!!! THIS EMITS TO ALL CONNECTED BROWSERS
                                                    status: r.report_status,
                                                    uniq_id: r.uniq_id
                                                }); //...socket
                                                if ((r.report_status >= 0) && (socket)) { 
                                                    logger.log('debug', 'polling...');
                                                    _.delay(poll, 2000, socket);
                                                }

                                            }); //get rerpot
                                        }; //end poll
                                        socket.on('disconnect', function () {
                                            socket=null;
                                        });
                                        poll(socket);

                                    } // else we're in the middle
                                } //done checking status
                            } //end of seq
                        });
                    return res.send();
                });
            });

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: To clarify, your `socket.emit('update')` sends to all clients?  Or just other emits below it?

Comment: The other emits below it - I will clarify question.

Comment: Can you show us the actual code that is failing?

Comment: There are a lot of nested callbacks between app.post() and the emit statement, but my edit should show the structure.

Comment: I think your edit shows the problem.  You had another function with another callback.  I think your `socket` object isn't always what you think it is.

Comment: Ahhh, how many times is that going to bite me? The code is part of a queue manager where asynchronous callbacks from db writes are happening all over the place. The callbacks may not be passing the socket explicitly.

Comment: Now your edit is gone... I don't really know how to help you if we can't see the broken code.

Comment: Apologies - the code is very embedded. I'll debug it based on your hunch and if I don't succeed I will post a more thorough example. Thank you!

Comment: Updated code, problem still persists despite encapsulating the scope of `socket` everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is not clear how to help you I can tell what's going on in your code:

```
app.post('/api/users', function (req, res) {
  // some code
  io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    // some code
  });
});
```

Whenever a user POSTs something to `/api/users` **a new handler is attached** to `io.sockets` (that's what `.on` does). But these handlers are never removed, so each time a new connection is established **all** attached handlers fire. That's where your broadcasting comes from.

You have to separate `app.post(...)` from `io.sockets.on('connection',...)` (they should be independent, both defined at module level, not nested). I'm sure it won't be easy (you will probably have to authenticate a user twice for example) but that's the only reasonable way.

Comment: Could you repeat...how then do I tell socket.io to send a message to a specific browser? that post only happens once a session. I originally had the socket.io code at the module level, but moved it into post to try to debug this issue.

Comment: @metalaureate Whenever a user connects to the server you have to authenticate him one more time, i.e. you send the session id **via socket.io** and do the authentication **in socket.io**. Now when you already know which user you are dealing with you have to define a global object which will hold **all** connections/sockets (with the data which user is using which connection). Now when a user does POST request you find him in that object and send a notification to him. That's the idea.

Comment: Ahhhh, got it. Is there something on this page that address that task? http://socket.io/#how-to-use

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't put your  `io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket)` inside the  `app.post` scope.

Just put it outside and try again, it will probably work correctly.

Listening to connexion should be done once when the server starts, not each time a client hits some URL.

Comment: -1: Obviously it won't work, because calls inside `io.sockets.on` require the request object. The code has to be heavily refactored.

Comment: Actually the accepted answer also suggests the same thing as i do : that the [code] app.post [/code] and the [code] io.sockets.on [/code] shouldn't be nested. obviously putting it outside alone won't fixe everything, but it's the way to go...